# Representing $\forall x\exists y:\lnot P(x,y)$ by an English statement

Tags: predicate-logic

Please help me solve this in an easy way:

> Write an English statement representing
>   $$\forall x\exists y:\lnot P(x,y).$$
>   Define all your terms first. Define $P$ and $x$ and $y$ first.

**Answer:** 
The answer then as I understanded will be : x is a student at harvard , y represents items on the cafeteria menu. P(x,y) means student x likes item y on the menu.So the statement will be : All students at Harvard don't like some items on the cafeteria menu.

Comment: What are your attempts so far?

Comment: I couldn't complete the statement , I am a beginner to logic

Comment: As an example: let $x$ and $y$ refer to people and say that $P(x,y)$ means "$x$ knows $y$". What would $\forall x \exists y \neg P(x,y)$ mean in this case?

Comment: Can someone please give a a complete answer

Comment: Any of us can. That will not help you learn.

Comment: The answer then as I understanded will be : x is a student at harvard , y represents items on the cafeteria menu. P(x,y) means student x likes item y on the menu.So the statement will be : All students at Harvard like at least one item on the cafeteria menu. (Now can you remove the hold)

Comment: You forgot the $\lnot$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the problem says, you need to start by defining $P,$ $x,$ and $y.$ Both $x$ and $y$ should be categories of things, and $P$ should be a statement about those two categories of things. Once that's done, translate the logical sentence to English directly.

**Edit**: If we let $x$ range over students at Harvard, $y$ over items on the menu at the cafeteria, and $P(x,y)$ represent the statement "$x$ likes $y$," as you've suggested, then you are *very* close, indeed. The one thing that you didn't take into account is the symbol $\neg,$ which represents the *negation* of the statement that follows. So, for example, $\neg P(x,y)$ would represent the statement "$x$ does not like $y$." How does that alter your answer?

Comment: I know that , but I can't create an example

Comment: What are some categories of things that are related in some way?

Comment: I'm sorry, but my answer is far too explicitly sexual and will offend too many straight people.

Comment: @user2715467: Good work. You're very close. Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if $P(x,y)$ is the statement "$x$ likes $y$", where $x$ ranges over people and $y$ ranges over things, your English statement could be the first clause of a well-known (at least in North America) advertising slogan.

The second clause is $\lnot \exists x \lnot P(x,s)$, where $s$ is the brand being advertised.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I've had that jingle stuck in my head for about $6$ hours, now.